# urlrewrite replace header

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am trying to replace page headers served by Jetty with Urlrewrite-filter by Tuckey.
I am using the following construct:

```
<rule>
<from>.*</from>
<set type="response-header" name="X-Frame-Options">ALLOWALL</set>
</rule>
```

This rule works but rather than replacing the header it adds a new one. so the page ends up with two headers - old and new.

```
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN  
X-Frame-Options:    ALLOWALL
```

Is there a way to delete old one? Or force the rule to replace rather than add?